# JBL Quantum 610 wireless connection problem

Tags: 20.04, quantum

I use ubuntu 20.04 LTS. If i plug in the wireless Usbdongle, i can't see it anywhere to use it. But Indicator sound switcher show me that the JBL quantum speaker (output) and the JBL quantum micro (Input) is found in the system.

What will I have to do, to get the headset working?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: If i use the Indicator switcher there will be an error and anything changes... and i can't change the jbl in the switcher... i hope there will be another way to get it worked

Comment: The question is unclear. What is "the wireless Usbdongle"? Is it a dongle to connect to the headset? If it is, then you can switch output to it and use its input.

Comment: It is a USBdongle to connect to the headset through wireless. But i can't switch to the output and use its input, how should i do it?

Comment: Why can't you switch if you have output and input available? What program you are using? Maybe you need to switch output/input in the program settings.

Comment: I can see input and output of the JBL only on Sound Switcher Indicator, and if i click there i only get an error message

Comment: Same problem - can't see anything

Answer (score 0):

A bug has been registred on kernel at: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216798

After this, issues from JBL Quantum 810 are solved on kernel 6.2-rc1 (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/sound/usb/usbaudio.h?h=v6.2-rc1) (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=303407&action=diff)

Already for JBL Quantum 610, its open changes but not merged to master/main kernel line. I believe it will go in version 6.2-rc7 (https://lore.kernel.org/all/20230118165947.22317-1-tiwai@suse.de/#Z31sound:usb:quirks.c)

If you want you can implement directly in your kernel, just patch from 6.2-rc1 and apply quirk from JBL Quantum 610

**@edit**
added quirk JBL Quantum 610 in kernel 6.2-rc7 (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/diff/sound/usb/quirks.c?id=v6.2-rc7&id2=v6.2-rc6)