# How to force Ubuntu to send an output signal into a detectable (but not shown) device

Tags: command-line, sound, output

I have an issue on Ubuntu 22 with JBL Headphones:
JBL Quantum 610 Wireless - wireless no sound only microphone
Subjectively it is closely related to this issue
[JBL Quantum 610 wireless connection problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434969/jbl-quantum-610-wireless-connection-problem)

However the suggested solutions are usually upgrading the ***kernel***.

That is something unthinkable for me considering a focus on LTS versions.

So let me ask more general question:

**If there's a device listed in `aplay -l` but it is not shown in the classic Settings => Sound => Output => Output device - can one force Ubuntu into sending the output signal into some hardware device using terminal?**

Comment: You can certainly upgrade the kernel on an LTS version. Your question  does not say you are running LTS it is the version number of Ubuntu Core.

Comment: PS : I can partially get closer with `alsamixer` where I can choose the target sound card, but then I can't adjust the volume @David that is irrelevant to this issue though (and I did not say you coudn't, just that it's unacceptable for me, since I assume LTS is mainly tested with the expected kernel)

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks, but pipewire doesn't work at all, `pavucontrol` I already tried - doesn't show, only thing that shows it somehow is `alsamixer` which sadly can't adjust the volume.

Comment: An LTS is tested and works with many kernels.

Comment: @David I wanted to be sassy, I won't. Many may be but not all. E.g. yesterday we've tested with kernel 6.2.8 and it does not load ... My bad is I though it's being replaced, but there's rather a choice to choose from all installed kernels. So I could later fallback to the one I know works. Still, not the point of this Q :-)

Comment: No 6.2 kernel is a supported kernel for Ubuntu at this time so no it has not been test. I was referring to supported kernels.

Comment: @David oh, ok, in that case it was just a misundestanding :)